# Editing a Mac Screen Recording in Premiere Pro causes image fragmentation

Tags: premiere, framerate, screen-casting, macbook

I'm making some tutorials about how to use a website. I'm using the built in Apple Screen Recording to record the screen on a Macbook Pro with a retina screen. I'm then loading the resulting .mov file into Premiere Pro to edit it and add some audio (recorded separately) to a finished version.

When I edit the footage in Premiere Pro the preview often fragments and after a couple of seconds shows an unfragmented view, but that unfragmented view is many frames, sometimes many seconds, back from where the timeline is. When I move frame by frame, it will show a slightly fragmented image, then jump back to an image from many frames back or several seconds back.

When I export to file by matching the sequence settings in the export options, it produce less fragmentation than I see while editing but there is still some. For some exports when I open the exported file to view in quicktime and hit play, it does not play the video, but if I scrub through a bit it will play and then I can scrub back to the beginning and it plays.

This is a screengrab of my Premiere Pro preview window after moving the timeline.

[image]

Is this something to do with frame rates in the original recording from the Mac Screen record utility? What frame rate does it record at )or is it some sort of dynamic frame rate) and is there a way of setting up premiere pro to handle that frame rate, or the footage that the Mac Screen Record utility creates?

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 likely causes:

1. I think Premiere still supports only frame rates up to 60 and your videos may be recorded with higher fps. Premiere tells you what the fps is, for example in Source Monitor, right click on Properties. Or in the Project Panel, you see the fps (you may have to scroll quite a bit or add the column if it's missing). If your material is beyond 60 fps, try converting it with any other tool, like ffmpeg.
2. Other users recently asked similar questions (see [[1](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/30683/glitches-in-premiere-exports)], [[2](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/30712/severe-artifacts-pixelation-when-using-cuda-rendering-premiere-pro)]), so I wonder if there is a bug in Premiere or certain graphics driver versions. If so, you could try to install a slightly older version of your graphics driver. Otherwise maybe contact Adobe support.

Comment: Thanks @Matt, I can see that the FPS of the video that has come out of the Apple Screen Recorder is 60fps (and the Video Codec is MP4/MOV H.264 4:2:0).  I'll try running the video through ffmpeg or handbrake first and report back

Comment: With "up to 60 fps" I actually meant up to and including 60 fps. I'm not sure if the conversion helps much because your source material should be fine then. But it can't hurt to try.